# schedule bash script without having root

Tags: bash, cron

I have one single bash **file.sh** and I want to schedule at every 10 minutes to run but the interesting part is that I don't have root privilege and I need to find anything else beside cron or crontab.

Thanks

Comment: You do not need root privileges. [`man 1 crontab`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab)

Comment: I don't have root password to have access doing that for non-root user.

Comment: You don't need the root password. Creating a cron job by running `crontab -e` is not a privileged oparation, any more than creating a regular file in your home directory. None of this is programming-related anyway, so unsuitable for Stack Overflow. Maybe explain your precise problem in more detail in a new question at our sister site [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

**1. Creating bash loop and add sleep time**

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    echo $PATH >> test.txt
    sleep 5
done
```

2. nohup in background

   **# nohup /home/sorin/test.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &**